# Integrating Kolab Mail server with OpenIMS HSS Database

Tags: mail-server

Im trying to install KOLAB mail serverv3 in ubuntu 12.04 as a sample mail server. In general Kolab can be used with OpenLDAP or Mysql db for authentication and authorisation. But I need to know whether we can use KOLAB user to be authenticated using OpenIMSCore's HSS Database as HSS database in OpenIMS is also an Mysql DB.
If yes, guide me in right direction.

Comment: You can select the reply as accepted answer, if you go this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate Kolab with HSS te the best approach will be using the HSS interface, rather than use the database.
To get more familiar with HSS, take a look at this [Oracle Docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/home-subscriber-server-083038.html) , on Understanding the Home Subscriber Server (HSS) Sh interface. 
You are developing the interface, take a look at [JAIN SLEE by Mobicents](http://www.mobicents.org/slee/intro.html) which implements the Sh interface.